# How to make "Featured post" visible only on my blog first page

Tags: blogger

This is my test blog / xn--90a.blogspot.com /
I true to make "Featured post" to see only on my blog first page, not on top of the articles.

Comment: Can you share Featured widget code here?

Comment: Hi Bassam, I have downloaded from here http://www.bloggerhero.com/2013/11/sensational-v2-responsive-blogger-template.html

Comment: I have just activated the Featured post widget in this template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the cond attribute `cond='data:view.isHomepage'` with Featured post widget like the following

```
<b:widget cond='data:view.isHomepage' type='FeaturedPost' visible='true'>
```

Comment: Is there a way the short text of Featured post to be on the right of the picture?

Comment: Will you help me, I have made the picture smaller and truing to put the short text of the description on the right.

Comment: Of course yes, just add this CSS code to your theme `.post-summary p { display: inline-block; width: 62%; float: right; }
.post-summary h3 { margin-bottom: 20px; font-size: 30px; }`

Comment: Please, If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted to help others with the same problem.

Comment: Glad it helped! To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.